# Code snippet manager that can run code

Tags: software-development, note-taking

I'm searching for a code snippet manager that can also execute a snippet. Additional requirements are listed below.

- Each snippet can be tagged with multiple tags.
- Search function that outputs multiple possible results.
- Syntax highlighting.

So far I've found [Reoon Code Snippet Manager](https://www.reoon.com/code-snippet-manager/) and it's been atrocious. Reoon gives you only one possible result per search and there are no tags.

I would also settle for a Visual Studio Code extension that does this but so far I was unable to find one.

Setting up a dummy project in an IDE to just check the syntax or try out a new library feature doesn't seem like a scalable solution.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: @Esther Mainly C++, Go and Python. The more languages an app supports, the better.

Comment: Can some online solution like https://ideone.com/ match your needs? It also exists similar tool that you can host locally but only for Python. It is named Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @mpasko256 How can I tag a snippet in [ideone](https://ideone.com/)?